# How do I change which interface gateway pfsense resolves to?

Tags: networking, internal-dns, pfsense

I've recently extended my network from one flat LAN to a couple interfaces using additional physical ports on my router and VLANs. I've kept the old interface up while I'm migrating and for testing and renamed it Legacy. The legacy interface uses a `192.168.85.0/24` network. My new network for infrastructure like the router, APs and switch uses `192.168.10.0/24` and is the default interface for untagged traffic on that port. When I ping my router using it's FQDN from any network it resolves to the gateway address of the Legacy interface. That is, from a host on the `192.168.10.0/24` range if I ping `pfsense.home.arpa` it resolves to `192.168.85.1` instead of `192.168.10.1`. I don't see anything special in the interface settings for my legacy LAN that would tell pfsense it's the "default" so I'm not sure how to change this. Searching for solutions has been very difficult since all the keywords I can think of like "default gateway" "hostname resolution" etc. are much more related to more common concepts of interface default gateways and resolving the name of hosts within a network.

Just to clarify, I'm fine with all my new networks resolving to one IP when pinging the router, I don't need each one to resolve to its own default gateway, I just want to change what that one IP is from the gateway associated with my legacy interface to the one associated with my new infrastructure LAN.

Comment: Home and Enduser questions are offtopic on serverfault -> [help/on-topic]. please move on [su] - have you seen [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/143039/pfsense-gateway-rules-by-ip-ranges?rq=1) Artikel which seems to be a nearly duplicate